# Express and Jade: getting a variable into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have the following issue: on the server side I am creating a graph. I would like to display this graph using the Sigma.js library. For reference, the generated data looks for example like this:

```
{ nodes: 
    [ { id: '423ed89a-491d-416b-9c19-13fcb6db45bc',
        label: 'Nevens Jens',
        x: 0.5935997352935374,
        y: 0.36792555125430226,
        size: 5,
        color: '#fff' } ],
  edges: [] }
```

In my Express app, I use the following code to render a Jade-page:

```
app.get('/network', function (req, res) {
    //Function calls to generate graph
    function someCallback(data) {
        res.render('graph', {graphData: data});
    }
}
```

Next, in my Jade file, I would like to assign this data to a variable so I can use it in a JavaScript file:

```
script(src='/javascripts/vendor/sigma.min.js')
script.
    var graphData = '#{graphData}'
script(src='/javascripts/graph.js')
```

My JavaScript file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    console.log(graphData.nodes);
    console.log(graphData.edges);
    var s = new sigma({
        graph: graphData,
        renderer: {
            container: document.getElementById('graph-container'),
            type: 'canvas'
    }});
    s.refresh();

});
```

The problem is, when I look at the console in the browser, it shows `undefined` twice.

Is this a correct way of transferring data to a JavaScript file? Am I doing anything else wrong?

Comment: What version of express.js are you using?  Also, if you inspect the HTML, is the data you expect there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're outputting the `data` object as a String so you're probably seeing something like
`var data = '[Object object]'` in you outputted html.

Doing something like this in your jade template should fix this issue:

```
script.
  var graphData = !{graphData}
```

Let me know that this helps!

Edit:  Update with Adrian's comments

Comment: I agree with @Brennan that you are getting `[Object object]` in your variable, but you should try to keep "processing" logic away from the template. I would use `.stringify` it on the server, using `JSON.stringify(graphData)` in the `res.render` method. If you processo n the server, you need to update the template so your variable looks like this: `var graphData = !{graphData}`.

Comment: An excellent point.  I've updated my answer.  This is much better.  Thanks @Adrian.